# Convert pure for loop into for loop using cursor

Tags: plsql

Please, help me to convert this loop statement:

```
BEGIN
   FOR employee_rec in (SELECT * FROM BONUS)
   LOOP
      IF employee_rec.BONVALUE > 500 THEN
        UPDATE BONUS
        SET BONUS.TAX = BONUS.BONVALUE * 0.12 WHERE employee_rec.BONVALUE = BONUS.BONVALUE;
      ELSIF 
      -- ...
      END IF;

   END LOOP;
END;
```

into statement where `CURSOR` being used.

Comment: Generally we would like to see what sort of attempt you have made at solving the problem yourself - as well as where you are hitting problems. Requests for code generally don't go very well.

Comment: I didn't make attempt bc I don't fully understand syntax and usage of `cursor`. Hope example of conversion will clarify for me both aspects.

Comment: You're already using a cursor. That's what the `SELECT * FROM BONUS` is. If you want to name that cursor, well, it's not that difficult... simply define a cursor in the declaration section and give it a name. However, it looks like in this instance, you don't need a cursor-for-loop at all; I'm guessing that the other IF clauses are also updates to the bonus table? If so, you ought to be able to achieve this in a single update statement

Comment: As an aside, I've met a lot of Oracle developers in my time who (wrongly) don't refer to an implicit cursor as a cursor. Just an observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a loop based on an *implicit* cursor definition. It sounds like you want a loop based on an *explicit* cursor definition.

As mentioned in the comments. Just define your cursor *explicitly* in the declaration section.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cur_bonus IS
   SELECT *
   FROM bonus;
BEGIN
   FOR employee_rec IN cur_bonus
   LOOP
      IF employee_rec.BONVALUE > 500 THEN
        UPDATE BONUS
        SET BONUS.TAX = BONUS.BONVALUE * 0.12 WHERE employee_rec.BONVALUE = BONUS.BONVALUE;
      ELSIF 
      -- ...
      END IF;

   END LOOP;
END;
```